# tesseract does not worked although I installed it and add it to the Path

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have installed tesseract 64 bit from this [page](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki).

I also add "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR" to the system path. I went to "System Properties", then "Advanced" tab, then I clicked on "Environment Variables...". then I added "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR" to both path for user and system variables.
 In command prompt I typed "cd C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR" and then "tesseract" and I got the following information:

```
Usage:
  tesseract --help | --help-extra | --version
  tesseract --list-langs
  tesseract imagename outputbase [options...] [configfile...]

OCR options:
  -l LANG[+LANG]        Specify language(s) used for OCR.
NOTE: These options must occur before any configfile.

Single options:
  --help                Show this help message.
  --help-extra          Show extra help for advanced users.
  --version             Show version information.
  --list-langs          List available languages for tesseract engine.
```

However, when I want to use it on anaconda python notebook I get the following error:

```
TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path`enter code here`
```

Comment: Can you please specify how u're setting the variable in windows system variables.

Comment: @JayVasant I followed the instructions in this video and did exactly what he did: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YM8j9dzuKsk

Comment: I am also facing same problem. try this -> https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki

Comment: When I use pytesseract on Windows, I always have to tell it where the executable is: `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have successfully installed tesseract on your machine. You are just not able to use it in your code. 
To use tesseract installed on the machine in your python code, you should consider using **pytesseract** package as well. You can install pytesseract using a package manager. 
Further reading on [pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/)

Comment: I have already installed it : Requirement already satisfied: pytesseract in c:\users\...\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\....\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages (from pytesseract) (5.3.0)